# How to optimize a MySQL query joining three tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a query join 3 tables for sales with about 15000 rows. The query takes about 22 seconds to respond, this is too big for me. How can I optimize this query? I use Laravel and use the filter from the form.

Here is my query :

```
$data = DB::table('crm_donhang as dh')
    ->select('dh.id as id', 'madh', 'dh.created_at as ngaybg', 'ngayxn', 'dh.trangthai', 'dh.createdby as nhanvienbh', 'tongtien', 'dh.updated_at', 'dh.updatedby',
                'ngayyc', 'tenkhachhang', 'tenloai', 'loaidiachi', 'dh.danhgia', 'dh.nguyennhan')
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT id_donhang, masp FROM crm_donhang_ct as ct INNER JOIN crm_sanpham  as sp ON sp.id=ct.id_sanpham) as ctdh'), 'ctdh.id_donhang', '=', 'dh.id')
    ->join('crm_khachhang as kh', 'kh.id', '=', 'dh.id_khachhang')
    ->join('crm_cfg_loaidh as ldh', 'ldh.id', '=', 'dh.id_loaidh')
    ->join('crm_cfg_dcgiaohang as dc', 'dc.id', '=', 'dh.id_dcgiaohang')
    ->get();
```

I have an old database, I copied the crm_sanpham table into it after trying the query for 0.5 seconds, while in the new database it took 4.7 seconds. What happened? (While the 2 tables are identical, the installed database is the same).

```
select `id`, `masp`, `ketcau`, `mota`, `donvitinh`, `dongia`, `trangthai`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `createdby`, `updatedby` 
from `crm_sanpham` where `masp` != "TANDUNG" order by `masp` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the execution plan of that query and your attempts to resolv ethe problem

Comment: If your records go higher it will be very slow.

Comment: It it was me I'd start with the sql.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can give the id of your **crm_donhang** table as a foreign key to the other tables, and after that just remove those joins and just access just your **crm_donhang** table and access those tables whenever you needed.
Please go to the following link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

With this, you do not need to use JOIN in your query, JOIN slow the run time of your query.

Comment: But it is required to retrieve data. I tried the above check (Fixed my question), please help me see what happened?

Comment: For example, if your records reach up to 100000 or more, those JOIN is not a good idea.